# How can I make sure to fetch only the x most recent posts in DB?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fiigure out how exacly I should make sure that I only fetch the most recent x posts from the DB.

My current fetch methods work as follows:

```
GetPeopleIFollowAnd loop over each UID
        For each UID fetch his posts
```

By doing this however I cant efficiently (quickly) fetch only the most recent x posts. **How can I do this?**

Some possible ideas I have:

- Create a new Node which, every time that one of your followers makes a post, they will be added beneath your UID with a timeStamp. So When I fetch I loop through this FollowersWhoCreatedRecently for each UID and only do so for the first 10

Problems I see with the above solution is that if a user were to have a millions of people following them this would be horribly slow when it comes to updating every single one of those million

[I have found this which seems like it may be of use. How could I use this?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)

My DB structure for posts is as follows

```
Post
  UID
    postID
       Media
          media
             image: URL
```

Based in a follower structure like:

```
WhoFollowsMeNode/UID/uid: true
```

I would have to, every time a user posts, loop through this list where for each user I would add the post to there timeLine... That seems undoable, and yet that what it seems they are [doing here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Realtime Database, you can make use of `limitToLast()` method, you can then pass how many elements you want to bring, this method will fetch the last information that has been added in a node, since the documents are ordered with a timestamp, if you fetch them with `limitToLast(10)` you can get the last 10 posts of a user.

If you are working with a List of posts, you can invert the list when showing it to the user, doing this, you will see the most recent data first and the old data below.

Comment: So this would mean that I would be going with the bulleted idea then?

Comment: No, it means that if you are showing a list of posts to an user, you can invert the list to get the most recent ones , or use limitToLast(postqty) to filter the latest posts that a user has created

Comment: Based on the way I fetch I would have to go to the node of each user and then his posts and the way i get UIDs is in no real order thus the most recent posts will not be fetched.